# Meteor 1.3 - how to load third party site in iframe through proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iframe, proxy

**CONTEXT**

I am using Meteor 1.3, React, Mantra framework and loading a third party website within an iframe that's within one of my components.

**PROBLEM**

I need to inject a JS script into the third party website as it is being loaded, which means I will need to use Proxy to bypass the cross-origin policy. How can I achieve this with Meteor?